# Identifier not declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm tring to run this code in SQL. It returns `identifier not declared patient_t`.i already created patient_t type/object.and also i tried patient_t%rowtype

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PATIENT_DATA_SERVICES AS

function get_patient_id
( p_first_name in varchar2
, p_last_name  in varchar2
) return number
;

function get_patient_record
( p_patient_id in number
) return  patient_t
;

END PATIENT_DATA_SERVICES;
```

Comment: Is this Oracle? What is the code to create the type `patient_t`? It appears as though you have not created this object / type.

Comment: Which RDBMS system are you using?

Comment: You need to create the patient_t type. Check if it is being created after this in your script, or if it is not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the type `patient_t` in the PL/SQL package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PATIENT_DATA_SERVICES AS

TYPE patient_t IS RECORD (id NUMBER(15), ...);

function get_patient_id
( p_first_name in varchar2
, p_last_name  in varchar2
) return number
;

function get_patient_record
( p_patient_id in number
) return  patient_t
;

END PATIENT_DATA_SERVICES;
```

Should `patient_t` be a table in your database, the function can be declared like this:

```
function get_patient_record (p_patient_id in number) return patient_t%ROWTYPE;
```

Comment: i already created patient_t type/object and i tried to run the above code but facing the same error ERROR at line 11: PLS-00905: object SOADEMO.PATIENT_T is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Remove %rowtype.   %rowtype is meant for TABLE or CURSOR.   patient_t is TYPE as you created.

```
function get_patient_record
( p_patient_id in number
) return  patient_t
;
```